# Images don't load sometimes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, adobe-brackets

i'm using Brackets to develop this page and bootstrap 4, but I'm facing a problem:

When I open Brackets and open the page using the livr preview, everything is ok, every single image is displaying ok, but when I just open the page with Chrome, Firefox or IE, the images are not loading (actually just one)

The page is in portuguese, I'm sorry for that, but the code it's ok.

```
HTML: https://pastebin.com/4tK96DFW
CSS:  https://pastebin.com/6gN3R9CR
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with images being read/rendered by the browsers. I suggest to upload them somewhere online to be served by a web server if you don't have one running locally.

Comment: But it's wierd...the live preview uses chrome, but when I open the page not using it..the images wont display ;

Answer (score 2):

I have had a quick browse through your HTML code and noticed that some of your  tags are not consistent and I wonder whether this is affecting whether it displays the image or not. Sometimes you have used a / at the beginning of the  and other times not. For example, I noticed the following:

`<img class="img-fluid" src="/Imagens/gow4.jpg">`

but then other instances where you have written:

`<img class="img-thumbnail logo-para-cel" src="Imagens/Logo-1.png">`

So the key thing here is that in the first img tag, you have started the src with a / but in the second src there is no /

I'll save you from me going into too much detail about this, but I wondered whether you could check and post back the html code just for the image that you said was displaying properly - and I'll see if it helps us to figure out why all of the images aren't showing.